# Exercise 5.24, Isaacs's Character Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

> Let $G$ be a doubly transitive permutation group on $\Omega$ and let $\alpha,\beta\in \Omega$ with $\alpha\neq \beta$. Let $\phi\in Irr(G_\alpha)$ and assume that $\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}}\in Irr(G_{\alpha\beta}).$ Show that $[\phi^G,\phi^G]\leq 2$.(Isaacs exercise 5.24)

The hint says to use the Mackey theorem.

---

Here is what I have gotten so far:

Since $G$ is doubly transitively on $\Omega$, we can decompose $G$ as $G={G_\alpha}\dot\cup{G_\alpha}g{G_\alpha}$ for any $g\notin G_\alpha$.

By the Mackey theorem, we can write
$$ (\phi^G)|_{G_\alpha}=\phi+((\phi_g)|_{G_\alpha^g\cap G_\alpha})^{G_\alpha} $$
where $G_\alpha^g=g^{-1}G_\alpha g$ and $ \phi_g: G_\alpha^g\ni x\mapsto\phi(gxg^{-1}) $.

Since $\phi\in Irr(G_\alpha)$, we have by the Frobenius reciprocity:
\begin{align}
[\phi^G,\phi^G]_G&=[\phi,(\phi^G)|_{G_\alpha}]_{G_\alpha}\\
&=1+[\phi,((\phi_g)_{{G_\alpha}^g\cap {G_\alpha}})^{G_\alpha}]_{G_\alpha}.
\end{align}
It suffices to show that $[\phi,((\phi_g)_{{G_\alpha}^g\cap {G_\alpha}})^{G_\alpha}]_{G_\alpha}\le 1$.

Note that $\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}}\in Irr(G_{\alpha\beta})$, we have
\begin{align}
1=[\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}} ,\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}}]_{G_{\alpha\beta}}&=[\phi,(\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}})^{G_{\alpha}}]_{G_\alpha}.
\end{align}
We know that
\begin{align}
[\phi,((\phi_g)_{{G_\alpha}^g\cap {G_\alpha}})^{G_\alpha}]_{G_\alpha}&\le [(\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}})^{G_{\alpha}},((\phi_g)_{{G_\alpha}^g\cap {G_\alpha}})^{G_\alpha}]_{G_\alpha}\\
&=[\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}},(((\phi_g)_{{G_\alpha}^g\cap {G_\alpha}})^{G_\alpha})|_{G_{\alpha\beta}}]_{G_\alpha\beta}.
\end{align}
Now it is sufficient to show that $(((\phi_g)_{{G_\alpha}^g\cap {G_\alpha}})^{G_\alpha})|_{G_{\alpha\beta}}$ has at most one irreducible constituent $\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}}$ in $G_{\alpha\beta}$. Then I got stuck... Any hint? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would simplify notation if you wrote $G_{\alpha\beta}$ rather than $G_\alpha^g \cap G_\alpha$, where $\beta = g^\alpha$.

Then we want to prove that $[\phi,(\phi_g)_{G_{\alpha\beta}}^{G_\alpha}] \le 1$.

By Frobenius Reciprocity again, we have
$[\phi,(\phi_g)_{G_{\alpha\beta}}^{G_\alpha}] = [\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}},(\phi_g)_{G_{\alpha\beta}}]$.

But $\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}}$ and $(\phi_g)_{G_{\alpha\beta}}$ are irreducible by assumption, so the result follows.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I am confused with $\beta=g^\alpha$. $\beta$ is in $\Omega$, so $g^\alpha\in\Omega$ but what does this mean? Also, I think $\beta$ is a fixed element in $\Omega$, why can we take $g^\alpha$ to be $\beta$?

Comment: The fact that $G$ is doubly transitive means that $G_{\alpha\beta}$ and $G_{\alpha,\gamma}$ are conjugate in $G_\alpha$ for all $\beta,\gamma \in \Omega \setminus \{\alpha\}$. So $\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}}$ is irreducible if and only if $\phi_{G_{\alpha\gamma}}$ is irreducible. So that assumption is independent of the choice of $\beta$, and we can just define $\beta = \alpha^g$. (Alternatively, you could just choose your element $g$ such that $\alpha^g=\beta$.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But I can only figure this out by setting $\alpha^g=\beta$ and argue that $(\phi_g)_{G_{\alpha\beta}}(1)=\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}}(1)$ so $(\phi_g)_{G_{\alpha\beta}}$ can have at most one copy of $\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}}$ since $\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}}\in Irr(G_{\alpha\beta})$. It follows that $[\phi^G,\phi^G]\le 2$. I do not know why $(\phi_g)_{G_{\alpha\beta}}$ also has to be irreducible.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment,  $\phi_{\alpha\beta}$ irreducible implies $\phi_{\alpha\gamma}$ irreducible for all $\gamma \in \Omega \setminus \{\alpha\}$. Choose $\gamma = \alpha^{g^{-1}}$ and conjugate to get that $ (\phi_g)_{\alpha^g\gamma^g} = (\phi_g)_{\beta\alpha}$ is  irreducible.

Comment: That is exactly where I am confused. I understand that $G_{\alpha\beta}$ and $G_{\alpha\gamma}$ are conjugate in $G_\alpha$. But how to argue that $\phi_{G_{\alpha\beta}}\in Irr(G_{\alpha\beta})\iff\phi_{G_{\alpha\gamma}}\in Irr(G_{\alpha\gamma}) $?

Comment: That follows from the fact that characters take the same values on conjugate elements, and the irreducibility of a character is determined by its list of values (because $\phi$ irreducible iff $\langle phi,\phi \rangle = 1$).